# Defining a function and showing it is an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group. Let $a \in G$ and keep it fixed. In terms of $a$, define a function $F_a$ from $G$ to itself by the rule $F_a(x) = axa^{-1}$. Prove that $F_a$ is an automorphism of $G$

I know it has to be an automorphism, because it is going from $G$ to itself

Comment: It is indeed an automorphism (part of a very special class of automorphisms, in fact) but be careful. There are lots of functions from $G$ to $G$ that will not be automorphisms; pick any constant map that sends every element to a non identity element of $G$. This is (in general) not an automorphism, but a map from $G$ to $G$ nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $F_a:x \to axa^{-1}$ is an automprphism, one needs to establish three things:  (i.)  $F_a$ is a homomorphism; (ii.)  $F_a$ is injective; and (iii.) $F_a$ is surjective.  As for (i), note that $F_a(xy) = axya^{-1} = axa^{-1}aya^{-1} = F_a(x) F_a(y)$; for (ii), we see that if $F_a(x) = F_a(y)$, then $axa^{-1} = aya^{-1}$ from which $x =y$ readily follows; and as for (iii), for any $x \in G$ set $y = a^{-1}xa$, so that $F_a(y) = aya^{-1} = aa^{-1}xaa^{-1} = x$, showing $F_a$ is surjective.  We have thus proved items (i)-(iii); $F_a$ is an automorphism of $G$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $F_a'(x)=a^{-1}xa$, what can you say about $F_a\circ F_a'$ and $F_a'\circ F_a$? You'll also need to show that $F_a$ is a group homomorphism.